# How do I check a user's current location?

Tags: javascript, php, gps

I'm trying to develop a web application that gets the user's location (or more specifically, GPS if that is even possible). I've seen some web applications requesting my permission to access my location and that is where I got the idea. I wonder if that is possible and if I should/could use PHP/JavaScript for that.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geolocation is a new function in html5, you can access it through javascript with the following method - `getCurrentPosition()`. Check out this link - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp